# Google Sheets IF Statement with Numbers and Text

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm looking through cells L5 through L9, and if the sum of those cells is equal to 0 AND one (or more) of the cells contains the letter T, then put the letter T into cell L10. If either one of those conditions aren't met, then put the sum of those cells instead. This is what I'm trying:

```
=IF((AND(SUM(L5:L9)=0.00, REGEXMATCH(L5:L9,"T")), "T", SUM(L5:L9)))
```

but I'm coming up with ERROR! Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: does `=IF((REGEXMATCH(L5:L9,"T"), "T", SUM(L5:L9)))` throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXMATCH` is for s single string, not array

Try to join the array of string with `JOIN`

Also, there is problem in your are brackets.

```
=IF(AND(SUM(L5:L9)=0.00, REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,L5:L9),"T")), "T", SUM(L5:L9))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF((SUM(L5:L9)=0.00)*(SUM(REGEXMATCH(L5:L9; "T"))>0); "T"; SUM(L5:L9)))
```